# Bias in sampling for set intersections

Tags: sampling, unbiased-estimator, bias

Say I have 2 sets, $A$ and $B$ with $n_{A}$ and $n_{B}$ elements respectively, which I assume is known.  I would like to estimate $| A \bigcup B |$ using samples of $\tilde{A} \subset A$ and $ \tilde{B} \subset B$.

That is if $\tilde{A}$'s elements are uniformly sampled from $A$, and likewise for $\tilde{B}$, will $ \frac{| \tilde{A} \bigcup \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | + |  \tilde{B} |}$ be an unbiased estimate for  $\frac{| A \bigcup B |}{| A |+|B |}$?  If not, is there some another estimator that will allow me estimate $| A \bigcup B |$ without bias?

Comment: The title says "intersection", while a union symbol is used in the text. Which one do you want?

Comment: Since $\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A| + |B|} + \frac{|A\cup B|}{|A| + |B|}  = 1$, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Does "uniformly sampled" mean *with* or *without* replacement?  It sounds like "without" is meant, but then how would it be possible for $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{B}$ to have *any* overlap at all?  (2) It is difficult to conceive of how this situation could actually arise: after all, if you can sample exclusively from $A$, you can identify members of $A$ *a priori*, and similarly for $B$, so why don't you know $|A \bigcap B|$ at the outset?

Answer (score 3):

$ \frac{| \tilde{A} \bigcup \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | + |  \tilde{B} |}$ is not an unbiased estimate for  $\frac{| A \bigcup B |}{| A |+|B |}$. Similarly $ \frac{| \tilde{A} \bigcap \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | + |  \tilde{B} |}$ is not an unbiased estimate for  $\frac{| A \bigcap B |}{| A |+|B |}$.  I think for the intersection you should be using multiplication not addition in the denominator.

To take a simple example, suppose $A=B=A \cap B$ and $n_A=n_B =100$ and you take a sample size $m_\tilde{A}=1$ from $A$ and a sample size $m_\tilde{B}=1$ from $B$.  Then $E\left[\frac{| \tilde{A} \bigcup \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | + |  \tilde{B} |}\right] = 0.995$  and $E\left[\frac{| \tilde{A} \bigcap \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | + |  \tilde{B} |}\right] = 0.005$ but $\frac{| A \bigcup B |}{| A |+|B |} =\frac{| A \bigcap B |}{| A |+|B |}= 0.5$.  By contrast $E\left[\frac{| \tilde{A} \bigcap \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | \times |  \tilde{B} |}\right] = \frac{| A \bigcap B |}{| A |\times |B |}= 0.01.$

The probability an individual element of $A$ is in the sample  $\tilde{A}$ is $\frac{m_\tilde{A}}{n_A}$ and similarly with an individual element of $B$;  the probability that an individual element of $A \cap B$ is in both samples is therefore the product of those probabilities, and the expected number of elements appearing in both samples is $E\left[| \tilde{A} \cap \tilde{B} |\right] = |A\cap B|\frac{m_\tilde{A} m_\tilde{B}}{n_A n_B}$.  So $$\frac{| \tilde{A} \cap \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | \times |  \tilde{B} |}$$ is an unbiased estimator of $$\frac{| A \cap B |}{| A | \times |B |}$$ and I think this is what you want.  The equivalent statement for the union is more complicated to state but easily calculated in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying to this thread half a year late.  I had a similar problem and came up with [this calculation](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15170448/Set%20intersection%20estimate.pdf).  It's not very rigorous, and I would appreciate another pair of eyes to look through it, but perhaps it can be of some help.  I only estimated the size of the intersection but, as you say, this is equivalent to having an estimate of the union.

Comment: I suspect the calculations in my reply are consistent with those in your pdf.

Comment: Suppose $a=b=3$ and $|A\cap B|=c=1$.  You take samples of size $1$ from $A$ and $B$; i.e., $a_k=b_k=1$.  Suppose both lie in $A\cap B$ (there's a $1/9$ chance of this).  Your formula estimates $|A\cap B|=1\times 3/1\times 3/1=9$ even though obviously $|A\cap B| \le 3$. Possibly you got the MLE right--I didn't check--, but it's looking like an awful estimator.

Comment: @Henry You're right: James' formula estimates $|A\cap B|$ by $\frac{| \tilde{A} \cap \tilde{B} |}{| \tilde{A} | \times |  \tilde{B} |}|A|\times |B|$, which is your formula.  It's interesting that it attains its lack of bias by occasionally making estimates that are mathematically impossible!

Comment: @whuber's first calculation suggests to me that it cannot always be the maximum likelihood estimate: there are four possibilities for $|A\cap B|$ (0, 1, 2 or 3) with likelihoods 0/9, 1/9, 2/9 and 3/9, so the MLE would be 3.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @JamesTurton. We appreciate your offer to help the OP. Answering late doesn't matter. But do make sure that you have an answer; this isn't the place or the way to ask a question of your own, so if you want someone to check your approach, you should ask your own question by clicking on the gray "ASK QUESTION" button at the top right of the page.